# let $\lambda, \mu$ be distinct eigenvalues of a $2 \times 2 $ matrix $A$.Then which of the following statements must be true?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was thinking about the following problem..

> let $\lambda, \mu$ be distinct eigenvalues of a $2 \times 2 $ matrix $A$.Then which of the following statements must be true?
>
> a. $A^2$ has distinct eigenvalues.
>
> **False** .Counter Example: $\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 &0 \\ 
> 0 & -1
> \end{pmatrix}$
>
> b. $A^n$ is not a scalar multiple of identity for any integer $n$
>
> **False**  .Counter Example: $\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 &0 \\ 
> 0 & -1
> \end{pmatrix}$ as this gives $A^2=1.I$ where $I=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 &0 \\ 
> 0 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}$ and so second statement is violated for $n=2$.

Am I right? Please feel free to comment. Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: Both counter examples are very good. Simple to understand and they disprove the statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment mentioned above by @5xum and to save this question from being unanswered,I just pick up my two counter-examples for the answer of this particular question.

> a. $A^2$ has distinct eigenvalues.

The above statement is  **False** .Counter Example: $\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$

> b. $A^n$ is not a scalar multiple of identity for any integer $n$

The above statement is **False**  .Counter Example: $\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$ as this gives $A^2=1.I$ where $I=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and so second statement is violated for $n=2$.